# Iterate over dataset with string replace

Tags: javascript, regex, loops

I'm trying to iterate over a group of `li` elements and replace their dataset attribute with a string.

The problem is, I only want to replace the part that matches another string and then leave the rest of their dataset intact.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="myUL">
   <li data-path="http://example.com/test1/">Link1</li>
    <li data-path="http://example.com/test1/test2">Link2</li>
    <li data-path="http://example.com/test1/test2/test3">Link1</li>
</ul>
```

And here is what I'm trying:

```
var UL = document.querySelector('.myUL');
var children = UL.getElementsByTagName("li");
var URL = "http://example.com/test1/";
var newURL = "http://example.com/replaced/";

for (i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
   var li = children[i];
   var datapath = li.dataset.path;
   if(datapath.match(URL)) {
        li.dataset.path = datapath.replace(datapath, newURL);
    }

}
```

However, this just replaces the whole URL with the string. I only want to replace the part that matches the string. So the output should be this:

```
<ul class="myUL">
   <li data-path="http://example.com/replaced/">Link1</li>
    <li data-path="http://example.com/replaced/test2">Link2</li>
    <li data-path="http://example.com/replaced/test2/test3">Link1</li>
</ul>
```

If anyone can offer some assistance, I'd be greatly appreciative. I wish there was a way to get what remains from the .match() statement, then I could simply append that to the new URL.

Here is the fiddle I'm working on http://jsfiddle.net/JLCMB/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to replace `URL` with `newURL` rather than replacing `datapath` with `newURL` which you currently have.

So:

```
li.dataset.path = datapath.replace(datapath, newURL);
```

becomes:

```
li.dataset.path = datapath.replace(URL, newURL);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/JLCMB/5/

---

I would also suggest that you don't need the if statement before executing this line.

```
//if(datapath.match(URL)) {
    //should work fine just with this
    li.dataset.path = datapath.replace(URL, newURL);
//}
```

Comment: Nice one. Thank you! I was almost there! I'll accept when I can